# How to get the first letter index of a string after spaces in Python?

Tags: python, string

Is there a way to get the first letter index of a string after an `n` number of spaces?

I know it is easily made with a `for loop`, but for sake of simplicity, is there a cleaner way?

```
string_1 = "    Hello" # Return 4
string_2 = "        Bye" # Return 8
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `strip()` cuts spaces before the first and after the last charactes (and multiple inside like `x   y`.

So:

```
x = '  abc'
x = x.strip()
print(x)      # result -> 'abc'
```

Comment: This is not what is being requested…

Comment: There is a huge chance, that: `this is not what you are looking for, but exactly what you need` kind of situation :)

Comment: Then more details should be requested or this should be commented

Comment: I didn't think of that. Thank you for the hint, I'll try to do this in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `filter`, `enumerate`, and `next` to stop whevener the condition is met:

```
string_1 = "    Hello"

next(filter(lambda x: x[1]!=' ', enumerate(string_1)))[0]
# 4
```